# Grails render as XML generates an unwanted class element

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I am rendering a command class as XML via

```
render foo as XML
```

where foo is an instance of the command class.

This successfully returns an XML for the objects value. However, the generated XML also contains a class element, e.g.,
    my.package.ClassNameOfCommandObject

This also happens when I do the same for a standard domain class, as well as when I use the encodeAsXML() method of the command object.

How can eliminate the  element from the generated XML?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look through the XML converter docs, they don't seem to have the option you need.  The simplest way (though a hack) is to simply generate the XML, and do string substitution in the resulting string.

[This thread](http://old.nabble.com/Configuring-XML-Converter-to-omit-add-fields-td15164001.html) may be of use - it goes a bit into internals of the process and where you could overwrite things.

Of course, you can always just use markupbuilder if you need something very custom.  [This post](http://jan-so.blogspot.com/2008/08/grails-groovy-xml.html) has an example.

Comment: Links are expired, please correct or remove.